# Which Linux distribution does Facebook, Twitter, and Reddit use?

Tags: operating-systems, linux-distributions

Most probably customize the base distributions, but I was wondering which one is more popular among most startups...RHEL, ubuntu, fedora, centos..etc ?

Comment: This is definitely not programming related...maybe superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

I think I read somewhere that Facebook has their own tweaked Linux version. However, you should go for the distribution which is the simplest to administrate. If you're launching a startup spending time on server maintenance is probably not what makes you successful.

Comment: @Merrimack: Yeah I figured they do tweak it, but i'm interested in know if they go the RHEL way or something like ubuntu and then start tweaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses Big-IP 9.4.6, which is high-speed network centric. Not sure about twitter but it's also going to be a very customized build

Comment: AFAIK Big-IP is a hardware load balancer, not a Linux distribution. It is however, a very good load balancer. We use them for our hosting